# auto schedule tasks via batch file

Tags: batch-file, schedule

I am trying to deploy one batch file which is including this line:

```
schtasks /create /sc DAILY /tn "RESTART" /st 23:00 /tr "shutdown /r /t 20"
```

when I deploy it via a deployment software I can see the new schedule on system32\tasks but not in the task scheduler and it isn't working at all.
dose anyone has any idea?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Probably need to specify username and password

Comment: windows 8.

I didnt try with username as It isn't a same username but I can try this also :) thanks for your tip

Comment: `schtasks /create /?` take a look to the `/RU` parameter (set it to SYSTEM to execute the task independent of any users - logged in or not)

Comment: @Stephan thanks for your suggestion. it is working on windows 7 but not on windows 8. I dont know what is the problem